# How to identify object types in java

Tags: java, class, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to determine an object's class (in Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541749/how-to-determine-an-objects-class-in-java)
>   [Java determine which class an object is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796151/java-determine-which-class-an-object-is)

I have following sample incomplete method to compare the object type of a given object

```
public void test(Object value) {

        if (value.getClass() == Integer) {
            System.out.println("This is an Integer");
        }else if(value.getClass() == String){
            System.out.println("This is a String");
        }else if(value.getClass() == Float){
            System.out.println("This is a Float");
        }

}
```

The method can be called as:

```
test("Test");
test(12);
test(10.5f);
```

this method is not actually working, please help me to make it work

Comment: Duplicates : http://stackoverflow.com/q/541749/1140748 ; http://stackoverflow.com/q/6149677/1140748

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You forgot the `.class`:

```
if (value.getClass() == Integer.class) {
    System.out.println("This is an Integer");
} 
else if (value.getClass() == String.class) {
    System.out.println("This is a String");
}
else if (value.getClass() == Float.class) {
    System.out.println("This is a Float");
}
```

Note that this kind of code is usually the sign of a poor OO design.

Also note that comparing the class of an object with a class and using instanceof is not the same thing. For example:

```
"foo".getClass() == Object.class
```

is false, whereas

```
"foo" instanceof Object
```

is true.

Whether one or the other must be used depends on your requirements.

Comment: This is so painful. Currently we have to [implement Pattern Matching ourselves](https://kerflyn.wordpress.com/2012/05/09/towards-pattern-matching-in-java/) in every project. [Proposal to add to language.](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/305)

Answer (score 30):

You can compare class tokens to each other, so you could use `value.getClass() == Integer.class`. However, the simpler and more canonical way is to use `instanceof` :

```
    if (value instanceof Integer) {
        System.out.println("This is an Integer");
    } else if(value instanceof String) {
        System.out.println("This is a String");
    } else if(value instanceof Float) {
        System.out.println("This is a Float");
    }
```

Notes:

- the only difference between the two is that comparing class tokens detects exact matches only, while `instanceof C` matches for subclasses of `C` too. However, in this case all the classes listed are `final`, so they have no subclasses. Thus `instanceof` is probably fine here.
- as JB Nizet stated, such checks are not OO design. You may be able to solve this problem in a more OO way, e.g.

  ```
  System.out.println("This is a(n) " + value.getClass().getSimpleName());
  ```

Comment: @PéterTörök Sorry I am completely tired and I mixed up the "== syntax" with the "instanceof one". I'll remove my comments as they are irrelevant.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet, no probs :-)

Answer (score 8):

You want `instanceof`:

```
if (value instanceof Integer)
```

This will be true even for subclasses, which is usually what you want, and it is also null-safe. If you really need the exact same class, you could do

```
if (value.getClass() == Integer.class)
```

or

```
if (Integer.class.equals(value.getClass())
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `value instanceof YourClass`